# vb.net authentification invalidcastexception

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, authentication, desktop-application

I am working on a desktop app with vb.net. I am using a windows form for authentication and I am using the code below for it and it says there is an invalidcastexception in "datareader(1).ToString = login.Text" I typed in the text area "admin" and this error comes out: 
The conversion of the string "admin" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.

```
If datareader.HasRows Then
            While (datareader.Read())
                If (datareader(1).ToString = login.Text & datareader(2).ToString = password.Text) Then
                    Me.Close()
                    FormMenu.Show()
                End If
            End While
```

Comment: Did you convert this from C#, maybe? What's that `&` and those *extra* brackets doing there? Change `&` into `AndAlso`. If you like the brackets, enclose the 2 conditions. (Btw, `ToString()` is a method. I know, it works anyway...)

Comment: it worked thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If datareader.HasRows Then
            While (datareader.Read())
                If datareader(1).ToString = login.Text AndAlso datareader(2).ToString = password.Text Then
                    Me.Close()
                    FormMenu.Show()
                End If
            End While
```